# JPQL ManyToMany select

Tags: java, database, jakarta-ee, jpa, jpql

I have a Many To Many relationship between two entities called: Car and Dealership.

In native MySQL I have:

```
car (id and other values)
dealership (id and other values)
car_dealership  (car_id and dealership_id)
```

And the query I want to make in JPQL is:

```
#Select List of cars in multiple dealerships
SELECT car_id FROM car_dealership WHERE dealership_id IN(1,2,3,56,78,999);
```

What is the proper way to make the JPQL equivalent?

My Java method signature is:

```
public List<Car> findByDealership(List<Dealership> dealerships);
```

I have tried

```
    //TOTALLY WRONG QUERY CALL!!!     
    Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Car c WHERE :dealer_ids IN c.dealerships");
    List<Long> dealerIds = new ArrayList<Long>();
    for(Dealership d : dealerships) {
        dealerIds.add(d.getId());
    }
    query.setParameter(":dealer_ids", dealerIds); 
    List<Dealership> result = (List<Dealership>) query.getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

Here is my JPA Annotations for such relationship in java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "car")
public class Car implements Serializable {

     //Setup of values and whatnot....
     @ManyToMany
     @JoinTable(name = "car_dealership", joinColumns =
     @JoinColumn(name = "car_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
     inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "dealership_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
     private List<Dealership> dealerships;

     ... other stuff (getters/setters)

}

@Entity
@Table(name = "property")
public class Dealership implements Serializable {

    //Setting of values and whatnot

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "dealerships")
    private List<Car> cars;

    .... other stuff(getters/setters)

}
```

**EDIT**

I also have tried:

```
 Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT c FROM Car c INNER JOIN c.dealerships d WHERE d IN (:deals)");
 query.setParameter("deals", dealerships);
```

Which threw the Error:

```
org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.QueryException

Exception Description: Object comparisons can only use the equal() or notEqual() operators.  
Other comparisons must be done through query keys or direct attribute level comparisons. 

Expression: [
Relation operator [ IN ]
Query Key dealerships
  Base stackoverflow.question.Car
Constant [
Parameter deals]]
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
select car from Car car 
inner join car.dealerships dealership
where dealership in :dealerships
```

The parameter must be a collection of Dealership instances.

If you want to use a collection of dealership IDs, use

```
select car from Car car 
inner join car.dealerships dealership
where dealership.id in :dealershipIds
```

Remamber that JPQL always use entities, mapped attributes and associations. Never table and column names.

Comment: It seems EclipseLink doesn't want to compare objects. It would work with Hibernate. Use my second suggestion, then, which compares IDs.

Comment: Thanks... just as a note EclipseLink doesn't like parentheses in the IN (:dealershipIds) part...

Comment: @GilbertoGaxiola: I've taken the bad habit of using parentheses due to a now fixed Hibernate bug. Answer fixed.